# How to key this equation with three braces on right side,

Tags: equations, matrices

Can anyone help me to key this equation, I've been struggling here for long hours:

[image]

Comment: Please give a sample of what you have done (so we do not have re-type the whole equation for a solution)

Comment: $$ \left ( \begin{array}{cccc|ccccc}
1 & a_{n-1} & \ldots  &  & \ldots& a_0 & & &  \ &\ddots & \ddots   &  & & &\ddots  & & \&  & \ddots&a_{n-1} & & & &\ddots  &  \& &  &1 & a_{n-1} & \cdots&\cdots& \cdots&a_0 \0&\cdots & \cdots & 0 &  & & & &  \\vdots &  & &\vdots & &  & & &  \\vdots &  & &\vdots & &  & & &  \0&\cdots & \cdots & 0 &  & & & &  \
\end{array}  \right )
$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a fairly basic implementation using no additional packages; regular `array`s. I've added an extra horizontal `\hline`, which you can remove if you wish:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\Vspace}{\vphantom{\vdots}}
\begin{document}
\[
  \left(\begin{array}{*{4}{c}|*{5}{c}}
  \Vspace 1      & a_{n-1} & \cdots &         & \cdots  & a_0    &        &        &     \\
  \Vspace        & \ddots  & \ddots &         &         &        & \ddots &        &     \\
  \Vspace        &         & \ddots & a_{n-1} &         &        &        & \ddots &     \\
  \Vspace        &         &        & 1       & a_{n-1} & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & a_0 \\
  \hline
  \Vspace 0      & \cdots  & \cdots & 0       &         &        &        &        &     \\
  \Vspace \vdots &         &        & \vdots  &         &        &        &        &     \\
  \Vspace \vdots &         &        & \vdots  & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\smash{\raisebox{.5\normalbaselineskip}{\mbox{\LARGE$N$}}}} \\
  \Vspace 0      & \cdots  & \cdots & 0       &         &        &        &        &
  \end{array}\right)
  \begin{array}{@{\kern-\nulldelimiterspace}l@{}}
    \left.\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}\Vspace\\\Vspace\\\Vspace\\\Vspace\end{array}\right\}m \\
    \left.\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}\Vspace\\\Vspace\\\Vspace\\\Vspace\end{array}\right\}n
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Using the [`array` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/array) one can ease the view on the per-row insertion of `\Vspace` (a vertical strut for even distribution across the structure).